# Kafka + Spark scalability

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-kafka, scalability

We have very simple Spark Streaming job (implemented in Java), which is:

- reading JSONs from Kafka via DirectStream (acks on Kafka messages are turned off)
- parsing the JSONs into POJO (using GSON - our messages are only ~300 bytes)
- map the POJO to tuple of key-value (value = object)
- reduceByKey (custom reduce function - always comparing 1 field - quality - from the objects and leaves the object instance with higher quality)
- store the result in the state (via mapWithState stores the object with highest quality per key)
- store the result to HDFS

The JSONs are generated with set of 1000 IDs (keys) and all the events are randomly distributed to Kafka topic partitions. This also means, that resulting set of objects is max 1000, as the job is storing only the object with highest quality for each ID.

We were running the performance tests on AWS EMR (m4.xlarge = 4 cores, 16 GB memory) with following parameters:

- number of executors = number of nodes (i.e. 1 executor per node)
- number of Kafka partitions = number of nodes (i.e. in our case also executors)
- batch size = 10 (s)
- sliding window = 20 (s)
- window size = 600 (s)
- block size = 2000 (ms)
- default Parallelism - tried different settings, however best results getting when the default parallelism is = number of nodes/executors

Kafka cluster contains just 1 broker, which is utilized to max ~30-40% during the peak load (we're pre-filling the data to topic and then independently executing the test). We have tried to increase the num.io.threads and num.network.threads, but without significant improvement.

The he results of performance tests (about 10 minutes of continuous load) were (YARN master and Driver nodes are on top of the node counts bellow):

- 2 nodes - able to process max. 150 000 events/s without any processing delay
- 5 nodes - 280 000 events/s => **25 % penalty** if compared to expected "almost linear scalability"
- 10 nodes - 380 000 events/s => **50 % penalty** if compared to expected "almost linear scalability"

The CPU utilization in case of 2 nodes was ~

We also played around other settings including:
- testing low/high number of partitions
- testing low/high/default value of defaultParallelism
- testing with higher number of executors (i.e. divide the resources to e.g. 30 executors instead of 10)
but the settings above were giving us the best results.

So - the question - is Kafka + Spark (almost) linearly scalable? If it should be scalable much better, than our tests shown - how it can be improved. Our goal is to support hundreds/thousands of Spark executors (i.e. scalability is crucial for us).

Comment: Your use case is doing a full data shuffle in the reduceByKey, which will I suppose get more and more expensive as you scale your cluster. At least, the global performance becomes bounded by the performance of the single worst executor performance, which can only get worse when you add executors. 

Can you try by using a Kafka partitioner to have all messages for a given id in a single partition ? It should allow almost linear scale I think.

Comment: How many kafka servers do you have in cluster? Do you have any partition replication setup between them?

Comment: There are many different parts to factor in. How many partitions does your Kafka cluster have? How big is your checkpoint interval?

Comment: @C4stor - reduceByKey should shuffle only results of the reduction within each executor - which should be quite small amount of data (1000 records per executor). We have tested also performance with 1 partition, but this was worse compared to scenario described above, as the Kafka partition is assigned to just 1 executor, rest of the executors are idle until next shuffle (i.e. the heavy-lifting = reading the data and parsing them would be done only on 1 executor).

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski - I will update this to the question - we have just 1 Kafka broker, as the server is utilized for less than 30-40%. We have tried to increase IO and Network threads in Kafka configuration, but without significant improvement (numbers above are already for setup with ~triple of IO/Network threads for the Kafka broker vs. the default setting). No partition replication is configured (as only 1 broker is used, it wouldn't make sense).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - partitions are described in original post, we got the best results when the number of partitions was equal to number of executors. 
Checkpoint interval - I have checked and we are missing the explicit checkpointing of the DStream (we're just setting the checkpoint directory for Streaming Context) -> will test this and let know the result.

Comment: @martinc For `mapWithState`, the checkpoint time (if not specified explicitly on the `DStream`) is batch interval * 10, that means every 100 seconds. That seems like it could potentially take time to serialize all the data accumulated in the state.

Comment: @martinc you're missing the point that when doing that, all executors have to wait on the slowest one. The shuffle itself isn't costly, but the waiting time may be.

Comment: @martinc I feel you might be reaching limits of single Kafka node (not necessarily CPU limit). Try spawning more (one per partition), make sure your topic is properly distributed between them and see if it helps.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski - we have solved this by 
- spawning Kafka cluster with higher capacity/number of nodes (in our case 5 physical nodes, 2 brookers per node -> 10 brokers)
- topic partitions = number of executors = 10
- setting proper default parallelism for 2-3 tasks per core
- batchSize/blockSize >= number of executors (so each batch will be properly distributed)

-> please post an answer, I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have resolved this by:

- increasing the capacity of Kafka cluster

  - more CPU power - increased the number of nodes for Kafka (1 Kafka node per 2 spark exectur nodes seemed to be fine)
  - more brokers - basically 1 broker per executor gave us the best results
- setting proper default parallelism (number of cores in cluster * 2)
- ensuring all the nodes will have approx. the same amount of work

  - batch size/blockSize should be ~equal or a multiple of number of executors

At the end, we've been able to achieve 1 100 000 events/s processed by the spark cluster with 10 executor nodes. The tuning made also increased the performance on configurations with less nodes -> we have achieved practically linear scalability when scaling from 2 to 10 spark executor nodes (m4.xlarge on AWS).

At the beginning, CPU on Kafka node wasn't approaching to limits, however it was not able to respond to the demands of Spark executors.

Thnx for all suggestions, particulary for @ArturBiesiadowski, who suggested the Kafka cluster incorrect sizing.